# Mathematical Induction proof for the following exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I have a question regarding following exercise. I have to prove by induction.
Given is:
$$
\begin{cases}
g(0) = 0 \\
g(n)= (y-2) g(n-1)+1
\end{cases}
$$
I have to prove following :
For all $n \in \mathbb N$ : $g(n+1) = (y-2)^n +g(n)$

Induction basis and assumption are clear but i get stuck in induction final steps for n=k+1.
Can someone help with the steps?

Comment: Is it right that the final solution in insuction steps is : (y-2)^k * (y-2) +g(k) +g(1)? Is valid g(k+1)=g(k) +g(1) ?

Answer (score 1):

$g(n)= (y-2)g(n-1)+1$ for all $n$

Suppose for some $k$ that $g(k) = (y-2)^{k-1} +g(k-1)$ (induction hypothesis).

$(y-2)g(k)+1 = (y-2)((y-2)^{k-1} +g(k-1))+1$

$g(k+1)=(y-2)g(k)+1 =(y-2)^{k} +(y-2)g(k-1)+1=(y-2)^k+g(k)$

Then $g(n+1)=(y-2)^n+g(n)$ for all $n$